# Debugger Not Connecting While App Is Running

Tags: android, adb, android-studio-debugger

I've this one app with which the Debugger fails to connect or identify each time.

When I click on the Debug button new debug window only shows the device and not the process. I've tried running the same app on a real device and an emulator, in both cases the result is the same.

[image]

I've checked the `build.gradle` file for `debuggable false`, but that is not the case either. I found another post stating the same flag in `manifest` file. I've looked there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking taking the snapshot for the dialog window for Process selection, I noticed the often overlooked CheckBox at the top left **`Show All Processes`**. When I check this, I can see all the running processes and select the appropriate one from the list.

Leaving the post for future unfortunate souls. However app should still show the running process by default, as it does with every other app/process.